# Will painless upgrading from Drupal 8 alpha 3.x to beta be possible?

Tags: updating, 8

I'd like to create a website with Drupal 8 Alpha 3. But I'd like to know for sure if it's possible to do a harmless upgrade to Drupal 8 Beta once that it's released.

I heard something about the Drupal 8 API being frozen, but after reading this article (http://buytaert.net/drupal-8-apis-are-freezing-but-not-frozen) i'm not so sure anymore.

Can anyone help out?

PS: The website i'm going to build is fairly simple (few content-types, views, blocks etc)

Comment: The beta isn't out yet, this isn't answerable until it is...any answer would be pure speculation. Best advice - It'll _probably_ be fine, but don't build anything mission-critical (read: anything that matters if you can't upgrade smoothly) with Drupal 8 until at least API freeze

Comment: Yeah, figured something like that. Thanks for confirming :)

Comment: "Confirm" is a strong word ;) That's just based on my experience with D8 so far - some of the core devs check the 8 tag here regularly, so hopefully you'll be able to get a more official response

Comment: I've added the 8 tag to your post, so they might find it :)

Comment: The title is asking a question, but the question text is asking another one. Are you interested to know if upgrading from 3.x-alpha is possible, or if Drupal API 8 is frozen?

Comment: I don't think that this can be reasonably answered at all until Beta lands. As far as I gather from the Drupalcon tweets, it sounds like [Migrate](http://www.drupal.org/project/migrate) is going into core, so I guess it *could* be relatively painless. However, as I said, until the beta lands, no-one can even nearly answer this.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is unanswerable at this current point in time.

Comment: @Chapabu for me it's more a face of "Primarily opinion based" - I can bet that there will be some modules or functionalities that will cause pain in the migration process, and it depends on the setup if it will affect any given user. Not to mention that opinion about "was it a pain or just an inconvenience?" is purely opinion based.

Comment: We will *not* support migration from alphas. What happens from beta X to beta Y is not yet known either.

Answer (score 5):

No.

Upgrading from a previous 8.x version will be supported starting with the first beta.

Upgrading from 8.x-alpha *will* break, I know of at least one issue that will make major changes to the entity/node storage.

Comment: Do you have a link to that issue by any chance? I've got a couple of custom entities that will probably need to be updated

Comment: Sure: https://drupal.org/node/2057401. It should only affect you if you support revisions.

Comment: Drupal.org/node/731724 will certainly not upgrade head to head